# How to fix "lazy" electricity to the cab of an '89 Mazda B2200

Tags: electrical, mazda, gauges

I don't know how else to describe it but as "lazy".  There's power to the speedometer/temperature/fuel portion of the dashboard, but nothing else in the cab has power, including the interior light.  Usually, even when full, the fuel gauge *usually* shows about 1/4 tank, and the temperature sits around the same on the gauge.  Occasionally while driving, they'll both start up to the level they should be at, but very soon drop back to the low positions.

I've checked all the fuses, and they all are fine, so am at a loss where the power is being "distributed from" and why there doesnt seem to be enough to the interior of the cab.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if the B2200 has it, but the problem may be a Body Control Module. In most vehicles today, the BCM controls such things as the interior lights and keeps the radio on for 15 or until the door opens. As for the fuel gauge, that is probably the sensor in the tank or maybe even the gauge itself having issues. I don't think this is due to lazy electricity ;-) Have you checked the bulbs themselves to ensure they work?

Comment: Forgot to mention it's an '89, so there's limited computers.  Checked everything electrical that a novice could check. I'm inclined to think it's electrical not the gauges, because if one rises, so does the other.  I haven't checked every bulb in the console, but they're ALL not working, so am doubtful that every bulb is out (though i did check the cab light, and its fine)

Comment: Check the grounds to the gauges.

Comment: @GDP Did you ever get this issue solved and do you recall what the problem was?

Comment: Nope, never did, and eventually sold it....could never reliably reproduce it for anyone to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestions in the comments, the symptoms described can also be due to lack of electrical power. This includes:

- ***excessive voltage drop***

  so the charging system works but something like excessive wire resistance is consuming power
- ***a malfunctioning alternator***

  which doesn't supply the required electrical power